# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: caolumn value

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i am fetching and match value from database table column but its give `exception no such column name` in android but`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column:speech` but speech is value in column but its give this error

i am using this code

```
 public List<TextJson> getDetailtospinner(String text_spinner1) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
   List<TextJson> textList = null;
    try{
        textList = new ArrayList<TextJson>();
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID,KEY_NAME};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_TEXTS, columns, KEY_NAME + "=" + text_spinner1, null, null, null, null);
        //Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_TEXTS + " WHERE " + KEY_CATE + " = " + text_spinner1 , null);
        int rows = cursor.getCount();
        if (cursor != null) {
            Log.e("0_0","0_0   1=>");
            for(int i=0;i<rows;i++) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    TextJson txtlist = new TextJson();
                    Log.e("0_0", ":( ==>");
                    txtlist.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                    txtlist.setText_status(cursor.getString(1));
                    textList.add(txtlist);
                }
            }
        }
        db.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("error","is==> "  +e);
    }
    return textList;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose where condition value with `'` if the values is not integer.

```
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_TEXTS + " WHERE " + KEY_CATE + " = '" + text_spinner1 +"'", null);
```

Comment: its give exception `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "'" (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM texts WHERE txt_category = speech`

Comment: yes now its not display value..... in listview everything is working but value is not diplay

Comment: @newdeveloper no, don't do that, use the second parameter of `rawQuery` instead

Comment: i use second parameter its working but value is not displaying in recyclerview

Comment: check your `Cursor` then: `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor`

Comment: i don't understand this .. hows doing this

Comment: what you dont understand? call `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor` method and see the `logcat`

Comment: i am using first time database  that's don't understand

Comment: @pskink please tell me how to call on `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor` in this method

Comment: @newdeveloper how to call a method in java?

Comment: @pskink my `return textList;`  return null value